# Why is Protractor currently "waiting", and getting the reason programmatically

Tags: protractor, wait

I've got an issue where Protractor reaches a certain page and hangs. There's no pending network requests, so some other Angular feature is keeping it waiting.

I'd like to debug why this is happening, and I'm assuming that the easiest way will be to get the current "blocks" on Protractor. How can I access this information?

Comment: Is there anything shown in the logs which can tell why is it waiting?

Comment: Unfortunately not. However, after some more research, it looks like it was due to the use of `$timeout`, but it would be nice to know for sure

Comment: Timeouts are explained quite nicely here: https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/timeouts.md